# Account association has given me a random username

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, linked-accounts, display-names

[image: My cool new username]

I had a few problems in associating [my account](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/users/3624/a25bedc5-3d09-41b8-82fb-ea6c353d75ae) on Fitness & Nutrition, perhaps due to the order in which I did things:

1. Posted a question as an anonymous user.
2. Once it had got a few upvotes and I felt less of an idiot, I clicked the register link.
3. I was going to use my Google ID to login but thought this may confuse the issue (irony) so used my Stack Exchange OpenID.  It accepted my details and asked for my approval to share information but never gave me the "Your account is also known to these XXX sites on Stack Exchange, would you like to link them" type message.
4. I ended up with a new account, with separate name and no association bonus despite having the same OpenIDs.

Overall, I wasn't that bothered so changed my name to Rory and then left the account alone.  When I checked back on it today I was pleased to see that the account had decided to associate itself but with the byproduct of this long hash in place of my chosen name (which is recorded in the history so it went through).

The username is also longer than the 30 character browser-side maximum so doesn't fit in several places on the site.

I'm not sure it's ever likely to repeat itself but someone might want to have a look at what happened, also could someone with the privileges please fix my username back to 'Rory'?  I'm time barred at the moment <_<

---

Also I've just noticed that I was sent a notification on my main account:

> Welcome to Fitness and Nutrition! Visit your [user page](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/users/edit/3560) to set your name and email.

Which as you can see is a broken link, apparently I now have a new User ID too.

Comment: Wait, I see the problem. The face you're making at the end of your post doesn't match the one in your avatar. No wonder the system thought you were someone else!

Comment: This problem stemmed from an error on your OpenID provider on login but that crazy username (literally intended for people to come complain on meta) should never be preferred as a "master" username on the site, I'll add a check specifically for that and [status-completed] this when it's done.

Comment: FYI I changed your user name for now

Comment: Looks like a hash to me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We added a check for this not to happen again about a year ago...then promptly forgot to update this.  Marking it [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) now.

Comment: This bug [seems to have come back](http://meta.ai.stackexchange.com/q/1265/75) for [this user](http://ai.stackexchange.com/users/3118/a25bedc5-3d09-41b8-82fb-ea6c353d75ae).